# Ran the xdebug wizard but still have php version confusion

Tags: php, ubuntu, xdebug

When I run `php -v` I get

> PHP 5.6.32-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)

So then I go to [xdebug wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php), paste in the output from `php -i`, follow the steps

When I run `phpize` I get

> Cannot find build files at '/usr/local/lib/php/build'. Please check your PHP installation

So I did `phpize5.6` and got

> PHP Api Version:         20131106
>
> Zend Module Api No:      20131226
>
> Zend Extension Api No:   220131226

which matches the wizard. Now when I run `./configure`, I get

> checking Check for supported PHP versions... configure: error: not supported. Need a PHP version >= 5.5.0 and < 7.2.0 (found 5.3.10)

However, if I run it like `./configure --with-php-config=php-config5.6`
I can get the end of the wizard. It says to

> Run: cp modules/xdebug.so /usr/lib/php/20131226
>
> Edit /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini and add the line
>     zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20131226/xdebug.so

But now I get

> Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20131226/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20131226/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_pass_function

So it looks like there is something wrong with the php installation. It seems to use 5.3, but `php -i` shows 5.6. Do you have any ideas on why that is and how I could best resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I solved this by first searching `/usr` for 5.3.10

This led me to see that I had used phpbrew a while ago, although I was using the system-installed version of php rather than the phpbrew version.

Switching to the phpbrew version 5.6 (instead of the system 5.6) resolved the error.

In future I can remove phpbrew and go back to the regular php following advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44655609/7462918).